# DataTables ajax on nested data

Tags: json, ajax, datatables

I am using DataTables ajax to fill a table. I was following [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects_subarrays.html) and it works if my json looks like their example, however my 'data' is a nested object in my json and then it is not able to fill the table because fails in getting the values from the json.

This json works:

```
{
  "data": [
       {"id": "myid1", "name": "name1"},
       {"id": "myid2", "name": "name2"}
       ]
}
```

But my json looks like this, and it does not work

```
{
 "result": {
    "data": [
        {"id": "myid1", "name": "name1"},
        {"id": "myid2", "name": "name2"}
        ]
    }
 }
```

That's my html (which works with the first json):

```
<table id="myTable" class="tabletable-bordered dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>                 
           <th>name</th>
           <th>id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And that's my js:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "/names",
        "processing": true,
        "dataSrc" : "result.data",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "id" }
        ]
    } );
```

As you can see I try to access to my nested `data` by setting `dataSrc` to `result.data`, but nothing is shown in the table.

I cannot change the format of the json response, do you know if then is not possible to use DataTables ajax with this json? Thanks!

---

**MY SOLUTION**

Finally (before getting an answer to my post) I went with the following solution, I first make an ajax call and then on success I create my DataTable.

so I only changed my js to this one:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/names',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        var myData = data.result.data;
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "data": myData,
            "columns": [
                    { "data": "id" },
                    { "data": "name"},
             ]
          });
     }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had more complex processing requirements so I implemented my own ajax function but I think you can get away with this:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
  "processing": true,
  "ajax": {
    "url": "/names",
    "dataSrc" : function(jsonObj) {
        // Just being safe here
        if(!jsonObj.results || !json.results.data) {
          return [];
        }

        return jsonObj.results.data;      
    }
  },
  "columns": [
    { "data": "name" },
    { "data": "id" }
  ]
});
```

Here is the reference for this:  https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax